# validating Symfony multi tab form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony form that has 4 tabs.
An element on tab 1 asks for Gender and is required.
If the user selects another tab and then clicks save, this field fails validation.
This is correct, but the user cannot see what the problem is.

How can I make the form switch to the tab with the error?

Comment: You should describe your problem with more details. Try to paste here your code, your actual view, your vision of right view. Your current question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not an easy answer for this question.

First of all, there are three different types of validation:

1) Validation made by the browser self (since HTML5)

2) Validation with the help of javascript

3) Validation with the help of PHP (or Symfony)

Now if you lean back in your chair and overthink what you are actually doing you might come to the point how to solve this.

If the form is not too complicated you could add javascript validation and disable HTML5 validation. Another approach is dividing your form into one form per tab. There are a lot of possibilities but the truth is that you make it complicated for yourself to put parts of a form into several tabs.

Anyway, add the novalidate attribute to your form element to disable HTML5 validation:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate>...</form>
```